# cannot set filter order for an array objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter, filtering

In my react project I have set a filter component imported in main component in which we have fetched an api and get the information of it as follows:

```
    fetchDoctors();
  }, []);

  const fetchDoctors = () => {
    const url = "...";   

   fetch(url, {
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
     },
   })
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((data) => {
        const doctorsData = data.data.map((item,index) => {
           return {
             id: +index + 1,
             name: item.Fname,
             lname: item.Lname,
             star: item.stars,
             expertise: JSON.parse(item.Specialties).map((specialty, index) => (
                        <>
                          {index > 0 ? " " : ""}
                          <span className="field">{specialty}</span>
                        </>
                      )),
           };
        })
        setDrInfo(doctorsData)
      })
     .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  };
```

I have imported Filters as this:

````
              <Filters clickFunction={clickFunction} />
            </section>```
and also rendered the result accordingly as follows:
``` {drInfo
                .filter(
                  (item) =>
                    filters.length === 0 ||
                    filters.includes(item.name.toLowerCase())
                )
                .map((item) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={item.id}>
                      <Doctors info={item} />
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
````

It works, but the issue I have is that I wanna do filtering according to expertises, and I find no  suitable way to substitute name in `filters.includes(item.name.toLowerCase())` with expertise that is an array.

Comment: You should not be storing JSX for the `expertise` property. Instead, create the JSX during the render phase in your component based on the state.